# How construct homeomorphism from $R^2$-{$(x,y)$ : $x,y$ : integers} to $R^2$-{$(x,y)$ : there are integers n,m such that $(x-n)^2+(y-m)^2<1/10$}

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

How construct homeomorphism from $R^2$-{$(x,y)$ : $x,y$ : integers } to $R^2$-{$(x,y)$ : there are integers n,m such that $(x-n)^2+(y-m)^2<1/10$}?

This is from 'Introduction to topology', Gamelin. I read his solution but I can't understand. Here is his solution.

'First construct a homeomorphism of a closed disk minus the closed disk with same center and half the radius, onto the same (full size) closed disk minus the center, with the additional property that it is constant on the boundary (e.g., for the closed unit disk, $(r,\theta) \rightarrow (2r-1,\theta)$. Then apply this to appropriate kisks centered at the integral lattice points in the plane.

Comment: There are two sentences quoted there. Do you understand what the first sentence says? Do you understand how to do what it says? Or is that part fine, but you don't see what the second sentence is telling you to do?

Comment: Now I understand how construct. Thanks for comment.